# There's Homotopy Type Theory so why not "Homotopy Set Theory?"

Tags: set-theory, foundations, homotopy-type-theory

If you have "Homotopy Type Theory" than does a more traditional "Homotopy Set Theory" exist too?

I think the simplest axiomization would be something like ZFC extended with a set of intervals with a nontrivial set of identities. I assume there would be difficulties with such a simple approach though.

Comment: The issue is that you probably want $a \in b$ to be a mere proposition. Since we have $(\forall x  (x \in a \iff x \in b)) \to a = b$, we know that equality between sets is also a mere proposition, since there is a reflexive mere proposition that implies equality. So there’s no room for interesting homotopy stuff to occur in material set theory.

Comment: @MarkSaving Very strange. So maybe using an isinhabited proposition could work? So pairing would be $$\vdash \forall x y. \exists! z. \forall w. \lvert w \in z \rvert \iff  \lvert w = x \rvert \vee \lvert w = y\rvert$$. Definitely seems more complicated than I thought though

Comment: So I figured out some of the puzzle while dealing with other silliness. The most organic ways to work with identity witnesses is in terms of fibers and images and inverse images. So you'd be working with something silly like $A \sim B = \{ x \in A \times B \mid A \in \{ B \} \}$. Not learned enough to think more about that.

Comment: why would you want a "homotopy set theory"? There are set like objects in HoTT, namely the 0-truncated objects. But, these objects are probably the least interesting objects in HoTT.

Comment: @IsAdisplayName would be simpler to model Homotopy Type Theory in Homotopy Set Theory. Also there's less need to make things compute.

Comment: Huh apparently extensionality is related to induction. I think you would have to modify well founded set theory to have path induction or something https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/nonwellfounded-set-theory/

Comment: Couldn't homotopy type theory be considered as a sort of refinement over constructive set theory with respect to the constructive nature of identity ?